# SSH to remote Mac that is connected to iPhone hotspot

Tags: iphone, macos, ssh, terminal, firewall

I am trying to SSH into my wife's Mac from my Mac. Her computer is connected to to her iPhone Wi-Fi hotspot. My SSH request times out every time.

I had her go to Systemprefs → Sharing, then check remote login and tell me the address to SSH. 
I had her turn off her firewall under Systemprefs → Security as well.

Is this a firewall issue?  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: @snd, please explain if your current setup is exactly same or some deviation?

Comment: @TarunLalwani from what's in the original question, it sounds identical. I'd just like to know if the agreed upon answer is that it's not possible to SSH to (or from) a computer that's connected to an iPhone hotspot.

Comment: And your mac is not connected to the same hotspot?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeah, only one mac connected to a hotspot

Comment: @snd, did you look at the answer I posted?

Answer (score 7):

So this a classic SSH/Connect behind a `router` or a `private` network.

In your case since it is a iPhone tethering which is a least configurable router, where you can't achieve what you want.

Next option is connecting behind a private network

```
Mac ---> iPhone --->  Internet  <--- Mac
```

Now this only work if your Mac is reachable from the other Mac

```
  ----------------------     ----------
 ↑                     ↓ ⟶ ↑         ↓
Mac ---> iPhone --->  Internet  <--- Mac
```

So below are the pre-conditions for this to work

- Both Mac have SSH enabled
- Your Mac has an IP `Y.Y.Y.Y` and is reachable by Mac behind the iPhone tethering

First the Mac behind iPhone will open a Reverse tunnel to your Mac using below

```
sudo ssh -R 4455:127.0.0.1:22 <yourmacuser>@Y.Y.Y.Y
```

Once this connection is made you can test on your Mac the port being available like below

```
$ telnet localhost 4455
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
```

Once the tunnel is open you can then ssh back to the other Mac

```
$ ssh -p 4455 <othermacuser>@localhost
```

[image: Reverse Tunnel SSH]

Comment: I have a similar case but with linux as the device doing the hotspot, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The public IP address in question is the iPhone's IP, not the hotspot client's IP. The cient IP is on a network like `172.20.10.1` and is unreachable via the public Internet.

Because the iPhone isn't configured to forward traffic to clients, to my knowledge you can't use the iPhone as a jump box using a standard iOS build.

Comment: I have a linux as a jump box, how can I get it done?

Answer (score -1):

Go to `terminal` on your Mac.

Type in:

```
ssh "username"@"ip address"
```

The `username` is the one that is your wife's computer login name and the `ip address` is the local address of your wife's computer.

It'll then prompt you to enter the password for access.

Comment: i did that and it times out everytime; however, right after i do that i can ssh into my webserver no problem,.. so i think it's something with the iphone hotspot or her computer

Comment: If it is necessary try and reboot both Macs as the newly applied settings may not have been reloaded